# Search the summary PDF 510k medical device of openfda

Tags: api, openfda, government

Is it possible to search specific terms within the summary or statement PDF of the 510k records of medical devices using either the API, the [dataset](https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/510k/download/) or an online database?

I found a similar question ([Open FDA - Medical device search -> summary pdf](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11752/open-fda-medical-device-search-summary-pdf)), however, the answer there does not fully answer my question if this is possible.

I loaded the dataset in R and tried to search the full text of the PDF but it looks like the full text is not stored in the dataset?

If it is not available, would it be reasonable to scrape it?

Comment: Unfortunately, for many items with a entry in `statement_or_summary` there is no PDF available from the FDA (see also [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20775/510k-summary-documents-indicated-on-openfda-are-not-available-from-fda-510k/20800#20800))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Jack with the openFDA team. At present the text of the summary PDFs is not included in the openFDA 510k API. We have no plans to change this yet, but I will bring it up with the team and look into adding this feature. As this would be a large feature addition, it will take some time to implement if it is determined to be a feasible and approved.

Thank you,
Jack Finch